# Overloading set < operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Given

```
struct node{
    int row;
    int cols;
    int cost;
}
```

I need an node's set ordered by path cost, a==b only if row and cols are equal. My question is how can I overload the operator< so the set can save diferent nodes but with same path cost? And also if a==b save the one with lest cost

Comment: You can't have different nodes that have the same path cost in a set if that is what you are sorting on.

Comment: Can you give us some example `node`'s and how you'd want them sorted?

Comment: for example,(3,2,3)  (3,2,2) (4,3,2) (7,2,3) will be sorted like (3,2,2) (4,3,2) (7,2,3)

Comment: @YunhaoLin So `(3,2,3)` and `(3,2,2)` are evaluated as the same Node there, but how did you decide which came first between `(3,2,2)` and `(4,3,2)`?

Comment: depend on the insert order

Comment: @YunhaoLin "a==b only if row and cols are equal" means you cannot at all consider the value of _cost_, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

> if a==b save the one with lest cost

You cannot have that using a *std::set* : `a==b` means `a<b` and `b<a` are false, so when *a* and *b* have the same *row* and *cols* `operator<` has to return false and that without considering *cost*

To have the expected behavior you have to implement your own *set* without just using an `operator<` to sort/insert.

> ordered by path cost

I suppose you mean *ordered on cost*

Using *std::set* and `operator<` we could think of having :

```
  bool operator <(const node & rhs) const {
    // to satisfy a==b only if row and cols are equal
    if ((row == rhs.row) && (cols == rhs.cols))
      return false;

    return (cost < rhs.cost) ||
      ((cost == rhs.cost) &&
       ((row < rhs.row) || ((row == rhs.row) && (cols < rhs.cols))));
  }
```

but this is wrong, for instance

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct node{
  int row;
  int cols;
  int cost;

  bool operator <(const node & rhs) const {
    // to satisfy a==b only if row and cols are equal
    if ((row == rhs.row) && (cols == rhs.cols))
      return false;

    return (cost < rhs.cost) ||
      ((cost == rhs.cost) &&
       ((row < rhs.row) || ((row == rhs.row) && (cols < rhs.cols))));
  }
};

int main()
{
  const node a[] = { {3,2,3} , {3,2,2}, {4,3,2}, {7,2,3}, {3, 2, 9} };
  std::set<node> s;

  for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); ++i)
    s.insert(a[i]);

  for (auto x : s)
    std::cout << '(' << x.row << ' ' << x.cols << ' ' << x.cost << ')' << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
(4 3 2)
(3 2 3)
(7 2 3)
(3 2 9)
```

the *set* contains `3 2 3` and `3 2 9` even they must be considered equals.

The `operator<` is wrong because it is not consistent when comparing `3 2 3` and `3 2 9` to the other values : `7 2 3` is less than `3 2 9` but it is not less than `3 2 3`

> a==b only if row and cols are equal

implies the sort must only take into account *row* and *cols* but *cost* must *not* be used

So for instance

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

struct node{
  int row;
  int cols;
  int cost;

  bool operator <(const node & rhs) const {
    return (row < rhs.row) || ((row == rhs.row) && (cols < rhs.cols));
  }
};

int main()
{
  const node a[] = { {3,2,3} , {3,2,2}, {4,3,2}, {7,2,3}, {3, 2, 9} };
  std::set<node> s;

  for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a); ++i)
    s.insert(a[i]);

  for (auto x : s)
    std::cout << '(' << x.row << ' ' << x.cols << ' ' << x.cost << ')' << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -pedantic -Wextra -Wall s.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
(3 2 3)
(4 3 2)
(7 2 3)
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

respects the expected equality, but nothing concerning *cost*

---

From C++11 (thank you @PaulMcKenzie for the remark) :

```
  bool operator <(const node & rhs) const {
    return std::tie(row, cols) < std::tie(rhs.row, rhs.col);
  }
```

very practical when there are a lot of fields to take into account

Comment: Hmm this was my first thought too, but it only works if the similar nodes are next to each other. For example, adding node `(3,2,9)` to the end of your array won't see it's the same node as `(3,2,3)`: https://ideone.com/OAxAmL

Comment: @scohe001 ah yes, in fact that means the operator < is not ok, I was afraid of that, but without trying that example to confirm

Comment: @scohe001 thank you, I edited my answer ... and come back to the very first version I given even I changed it ... because of you ^^

Comment: @bruno `return (row < rhs.row) || ((row == rhs.row) && (cols < rhs.cols));` -- Using `std::tie` removes having to figure out the logic and automatically does the cascading logic for you.  `return std::tie(row, cols) < std::tie(rhs.row, rhs.col);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes you are right, one of the C++11 gifts, thank you for the remark, I edited my answer